# Apache derby in-memory db schema dump with Hibernate 4+

Tags: hibernate, jpa, schema, derby

I'm using Apache Derby 10.9.x with Hibernate Entitymanager 4.1.9.Final in unit tests. The Derby db schema gets generated from JPA annotated entities. There is only a persistence.xml config file. I'd like to dump the generated Derby db schema during/before/after a unit test. What's the programmatic way to do that?

Solution:

```
    // should not be required because Hibernate already started Derby:
    //Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:derby:memory:unit-testing;")) {
        String cat = null;
        String schema = "ROOT";

        DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = md.getTableTypes();
        ResultSetUtils.dump(rs);
        rs = md.getTables(cat, schema, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
        ResultSetUtils.dump(rs);
        rs = md.getColumns(cat, schema, null, null);
        ResultSetUtils.dump(rs);
    }
```

public class ResultSetUtils {

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ResultSetUtils.class.getName());
private static final String COL_SEPARATOR = ";";

public static int getColForLabel(ResultSet rs, String labelname) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

    for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        if (labelname.equals(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    throw new SQLException("Invalid label name " + labelname);
}

public static void dump(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    // the order of the rows in a cursor
    // are implementation dependent unless you use the SQL ORDER statement
    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
    int colmax = meta.getColumnCount();
    int i;
    Object o;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
    for (i = 0; i < colmax; ++i) {
        if(i>0) {
            sb.append(COL_SEPARATOR);
        }
        String s = meta.getColumnName(i + 1);
        sb.append((s == null) ? "NULL" : s);
        s = meta.getColumnTypeName(i + 1);
        sb.append((s == null) ? "(NULL)" : "("+s+")");
    }
    logger.info(sb.toString());


    // the result set is a cursor into the data.  You can only
    // point to one row at a time
    // assume we are pointing to BEFORE the first row
    // rs.next() points to next row and returns true
    // or false if there is no next row, which breaks the loop
    for (; rs.next();) {
        sb = new StringBuilder(512);
        for (i = 0; i < colmax; ++i) {
            if(i>0) {
                sb.append(COL_SEPARATOR);
            }
            o = rs.getObject(i + 1);    // Is SQL the first column is indexed
            sb.append((o == null) ? "NULL" : o.toString());
        }

        logger.info(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A programmatic way to access the schema is to use the DatabaseMetaData class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

Start with the getTables() method, and print out the information that is returned.

Comment: I'd rather like something that is more Derby-native, ie. I'd prefer Derby to tell me what its schema looks like. Can't I simply execute "dblook" via some method call(s)?

Comment: Sure! Java programs can call other java programs. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/tools/ctoolsdblook.html

Answer (score 1):

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
    <version>10.9.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
new dblook(new String[]{"-d", "jdbc:derby:memory:unit-testing;", "-verbose"});
```

No args to print out help:

```
new dblook(new String[]{});
```

Results in:

```
-- Timestamp: 2013-03-09 00:19:49.733
-- Source database is: memory
-- Connection URL is: jdbc:derby:memory:unit-testing;
-- appendLogs: false

-- ----------------------------------------------
-- DDL Statements for schemas
-- ----------------------------------------------

CREATE SCHEMA "ROOT";

-- ----------------------------------------------
-- DDL Statements for tables
-- ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE "ROOT"."BLOG" ("DTYPE" VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, "ID" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), "BODY" VARCHAR(255), "CREATEDAT" TIMESTAMP, "RAWDATA" BLOB(2147483647), "SUBJECT" VARCHAR(255), "SENDER" VARCHAR(255));

-- ----------------------------------------------
-- DDL Statements for keys
-- ----------------------------------------------

-- primary/unique
ALTER TABLE "ROOT"."BLOG" ADD CONSTRAINT "SQL130309001949220" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
```

The JDBC metadata operations seem to lack a few things like indexes, triggers etc.

Comment: note if you want to store the DDL to a file for further processing (not simply output it to stdout), add the extra parameters "-o", "filename" to the String[] parameter of the dblook constructor.